# two-level hierarchy repeater in angularJS, without any output for the first level

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to generate a table in angular, which is nested in a two-level hierarchy which would thus need two nested `ng-repeat`.  An example data structure would be:

```
Product.Features
```

Each product would have a list of features, e.g:

```
iPhone
    3G
    ScreenSize
Fruit
    Color
    Size
    Texture
```

I have a list of products, and would like to output as columns the list of features.  Hence, the output would be:

```
<td>3G</td> 
<td>ScreenSize</td> 
<td>Color</td>  
<td>Size</td>   
<td>Texture</td>
```

The problem with this is that when using `ng-repeat` for the list of products, I cannot generate a blank element.  Also, I cannot use `ng-repeat` on it's own.  Some sample code could be (does not work):

```
<ng-repeat ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td ng-repeat="feature in product.feature">
        {{feature.Name}}
        </td>
</ng-repeat>
```

Note that the above code is a sample and **does not work**!

Is this somehow possible?  I saw some answers on SO mentioning to use `ng-repeat-start` but I still could not see how this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to flatten your list of products, and then you only need one ng-repeat:

In your controller:

```
$scope.features = _.flatten(_.map(products, function(product) {return product.features}));
```

$scope.features will be ['3G', 'ScreenSize', 'Color'...]

Then in your view:

```
<td ng-repeat="feature in features">
    {{feature}}
</td>
```

There's an [SO question about flattening an object here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786417/how-to-use-underscore-js-to-produce-a-flatten-result).

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing.  However, I find it strange how this is not something which can be done natively by AngularJS, and you have to flatten such lists.  I knew that was a solution, I wanted to see if there is a native solution to it.