# Separate different data in a response in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have to get the values of the following response.

```
var response =  { "data": [

    {
      "value": "Network problem",
      "text": "Network problem",
      "areas": [
        {
          "value": "Congestion",
          "text": "Congestion",
          "sub_areas": [
            {
              "value": "Congestion_1",
              "text": "Congestion_1",
              "id":"1"
            },
            {
              "value": "Call D",
              "text": "Call D",
              "id":"2"
            }]
        },
        {
          "value": "Drop",
          "text": "Drop",
          "sub_areas": [
            {
              "value": "Drop_1",
              "text": "Drop_1",
              "id":"3"
            }]
        }
      ]};
```

If I have the value `"Network problem"`, then I have to retrieve its areas`(ex: areas = ["Congestion","Drop"])`. Then I have to rerieve the sub areas using area value. If area value is  `"congestion"`, then `sub_areas =["congestion_1", "Call D"]`). How can I do it

Comment: you have to `flatten` this json object and then you can get whatever `value` you want.

Comment: @Venky Give me an example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890969/how-to-navigate-in-nested-json

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463233/how-to-access-nested-json-data

Comment: you can use `underscore` library to flatten a json object and get whatever values you want.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786417/how-to-use-underscore-js-to-produce-a-flatten-result

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Venky, using a library such as underscore is probably the best way to go.

If you're curious about a native JS solution, I will present one below.

Because your structure does not have many levels of imbrication, you can consider using a simple approach such as:

```
var node, root = {};

response.data.forEach(function(data) {
  node = root[data.value] = {};

  data.areas.forEach(function(area) {
    node[area.value] = [];

    area.sub_areas.forEach(function(subArea) {
      node[area.value].push(subArea.value);
    });
  });
});
```

Example output #1: list of 'data' values:

```
console.log(Object.keys(root));
["Network problem"]
```

Example output #2: list of areas for 'Network problem':

```
console.log(Object.keys(root['Network problem']));
["Congestion", "Drop"]
```

Example output #3: list of sub-areas for 'Network problem' / 'Congestion':

```
console.log(root['Network problem']['Congestion']);
["Congestion_1", "Call D"]
```

Note that the root node and its immediate children are objects, while the leaf nodes are arrays. Hence the different syntax for the last example.

**Appendix**

Below is the response object I used, with fixed formatting.

```
var response = {
  "data": [
    {
      "value": "Network problem",
      "text": "Network problem",
      "areas": [
        {
          "value": "Congestion",
          "text": "Congestion",
          "sub_areas": [
            {
              "value": "Congestion_1",
              "text": "Congestion_1",
              "id":"1"
            },
            {
              "value": "Call D",
              "text": "Call D",
              "id":"2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "value": "Drop",
          "text": "Drop",
          "sub_areas": [
            {
              "value": "Drop_1",
              "text": "Drop_1",
              "id":"3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```